# is it possible to develop a cuda program in a virtual machine that has a ubuntu installed

Tags: cuda, virtualbox

I saw a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRSxp5ZKwhQ) where a guy compiled one of his cuda program in a virtual box. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Please go to 01:09:00 in that video to see he compiled the program in virgualbox .

PS:
I have a gtx 970 card and the other graphic card  installed on my workstation, but I don't want to install a real Ubuntu on it, I just want to using a VM to test the cuda world.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to run the CUDA compiler (`nvcc`) in a virtual box that has cuda installed.  If you're looking for someone to provide you with a step-by-step tutorial, I think you're unlikely to get that here.  Having said that, you probably won't be able to **run** any CUDA code in a virtual box, because AFAIK there is no defined method to insert a physical GPU device into a virtual box instance.  I may be wrong about that, however.

Comment: thanks anyway,   I myself won't belive that too, but i saw he did it in the movie, so I am curious.

Comment: Oh, when you said virtual box, I thought you actually meant [the  VirtualBox product](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  The presenter in that video is using an Amazon EC2 cloud GPU instance, which is certainly possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The presenter in the video is using an Amazon EC2 cloud GPU instance.

In general, many types of VM (virtual machine) offerings can host a linux OS, upon which the CUDA toolkit could be loaded and codes compiled that way.

There is a difference between *compiling* a code and *running* a CUDA code, however.  Running a CUDA code usually requires a CUDA GPU be present/available.  This can be done using some types of VMs/hypervisors, but not every VM hypervisor supports the ability to place a physical GPU device into a VM (which is required, currently, to be able to *run* a CUDA code in a VM).

In general, to provide a GPU within a VM suitable for CUDA usage (*currently*) it is necessary for the VM/hypervisor to support some sort of [PCI Passthrough](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pci-passthrough/) capability.

Providing a full step-by-step tutorial would depend on the choice of specific hypervisor and is beyond the scope of an answer I can provide here.

Comment: Maybe you could write a genera tutorial, i.e Virtualbox + ubuntu +mid range nvidia gpu.

Comment: Robert, taking your advice into account, I installed only the cuda drivers onto my VM (and did not install the nvidia gpu drivers). That still didn't work--at least my VM would no longer boot with a display. Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure that PCI passthrough is enough for CUDA?

Comment: It's not sufficient, but it is *necessary* in the general case.  Certain NVIDIA GPUs are enabled for this type of usage, but many are not, and I can't give an exhaustive list or respond to specific questions about this GPU or that GPU.  The NVIDIA GPU driver may refuse to work correctly in a PCI passthrough scenario, and this will depend on the specific GPU being used, among other factors.

Answer (score 2):

In a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 18.04, I installed the NVIDIA CUDA compiler and dev header files with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-dev libcupti-dev
```

This gives me:

```
> nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

Comment: Suppose the Linux VM is running on a Windows host.  Do I need to install CUDA for Windows or will the sequence above allow me to both compile and to run?